# Make a div appear if another div is smaller than a specified size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 divs, `.about` and `.hiddendiv`.

`.about` is an area for the site owner to write their 'about' info. but I have no way of knowing how much info they will put in there. So I want to do this, if `.about` is less than 500px in height then `.hiddendiv` will show otherwise it wont. I have no clue how to go about this, can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
if($(".div1").height() < 500)
{
    $(".div2").show();
}
else
{
    $(".div2").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

$(document).ready(function(){
if($(".about").height() < 500)
{
    $(".hiddendiv").show();
}
});